# How do you keep a notification from disappearing when the app is killed?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-mediaplayer

I'm trying to build a media player, but I can't figure out how to keep the notification to persist when the user kills the app.  The music continues to play, but the notification disappears.  If I don't kill the app, the notification stays.  Oddly, it does appear on the lock screen, but there are no controls when it does, but that's a problem for another day.

Here's some relevant code:

```
private fun buildNotification(action: Notification.Action) {
    var style: Notification.MediaStyle = Notification.MediaStyle().setMediaSession(ms.sessionToken)

    var intent = Intent(applicationContext, MediaPlayerService::class.java)
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
    var pIntent: PendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
    var builder: Notification.Builder = Notification.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.small_app_icon)
            .setTicker(prefs.getString("EP_TITLE", ""))
            .setContentTitle(prefs.getString("EP_TITLE", ""))
            .setContentText("")
            .setContentIntent(pIntent)
            .setOngoing(true)
            .setVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
            .setStyle(style)



    builder.addAction(generateAction(Icon.createWithResource(baseContext, R.drawable.back10s), "Back 10 Seconds", ACTION_REWIND))
    builder.addAction(action)
    builder.addAction(generateAction(Icon.createWithResource(baseContext, R.drawable.up30s), "Forward 30 Seconds", ACTION_FAST_FORWARD))

    style.setShowActionsInCompactView(0,1,2)

    startForeground(246, builder.build())
}
```

stopForeground is called only twice in the service.

```
private fun pauseMedia() {
    if (mp!!.isPlaying) {
        mp!!.pause()
        resumePosition = mp!!.currentPosition
        stopForeground(false)
    }
}

override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    stopForeground(true)
}
```

Thanks for any help you can give!

Answer (score 0):

Try notifying the same notification before startForeground().

```
val notification = builder.build()
NotificationManagerCompat.from(service).notify(246, notification)
```

[Refer this project](https://github.com/UdeshUK/CoffeeMusicPlayer/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/udeshcoffee/android/service/NotifyManager.kt). This is a music player too, it use this method to show a MediaStyleNotification.